# How to enable ssl certificate in firefox using selenium2

Tags: selenium

How to enable ssl certificate in firefox using selenium2

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](http://garbuz.com/2010/07/31/running-selenium-with-custom-firefox-profile/) entry explains the use of custom fire fox profile. Follow [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/3dd0b1234a0257f) as well.